# Is it possible to create variable aliases in .NET?

Tags: .net, alias

Considering the following simple code :

```
Dim v1 as A
Dim v2 as A

v1 = new A
v2 = v1

v1 = new A
```

This code leads to v1 and v2 referencing 2 different objects.

I'm looking for a way to have v2 being an alias of v1, so that in the end, v2 would references the same object as v1.
Is there a special way of assigning v1 to v2 that would make the trick ?

Comment: Can I ask why? If `v1` and `v2` have different scopes you just push one of the two of them closer to "global" (bad in a way).

Comment: No. There's not. I'd be interested in why you want to do that in the first place.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: FORTRAN programmers can do that with equivalences...but it is usually a dirty hack or due to a lack of knowledge of other ways of solving the problem.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, `v2 = v1` will make `v2` reference `v1` automatically. This however is then overridden by the new instanciation. I'm quite sure that changes done to the object in `v2` will also show up in `v1`.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: the OP would like v1 and v2 to always point to the same object even if the reference changes. The OP is not concerned with changes to the members of the reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bizarre request and likely has a better way to solve it, but as with anything in computer science you can solve this problem with a layer of abstraction:

```
Public Class AContainer
    Private a As A
    Public ReadOnly Property A() As A
        Get
            Return a
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As A)
        a = value
    End Sub

    Public Sub Update(ByVal value As a)
        a = value
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now you just set `v1` and `v2` to the same instance of `AContainer` and you can then reference `v1.A` or `v2.A` and they will always have the same instance of A.

More likely you need to reevaluate *why* you need `v1` and `v2` to be the same, and instead use the same reference.

Comment: I know the question seems a bit weird. The thing is that we're using a library that manages objects within an object store. When it detects that the object is outdated and needs to be reset, it creates a new instance to make sure there's no trace of the old one. It's not good when I want to use multiples references of the same object, because at some point, the object could be removed and only one reference would point to the new object.

Comment: I'm thinking the problem might just be the library, and it shouldn't create a new instance, but instead it should clean the object properly... But it's a bit touchy, that's why I wanted to know if there was a way of creating aliases.

Thanks for the answers ;)